# libibverbs: mutlithreaded CQ events polling

Tags: c++, rdma

I use the function below for listening to RDMA events. Is this function `wait_event()` thread-safe? That is, can I process CQ events in parallel in multiple threads? I am concerned specifically about the safety of using `ibv_get_cq_event()` in multiple threads.

```cpp
ibv_wc RdmaBase::wait_event(bool ignore_errors)
{
    // This is kind of a coroutine instead of polling the events in a different thread

    ibv_wc ret{};

start:
    if(!m_polling)
    {
        void* ctxt;
        HENSURE_ERRNO(ibv_get_cq_event(m_comp_channel, &m_cq, &ctxt) == 0);
        ibv_ack_cq_events(m_cq, 1);
        HENSURE_ERRNO(ibv_req_notify_cq(m_cq, 0) == 0);
        m_polling = true;
    }

    while(true)
    {
        const int num_completions = ibv_poll_cq(m_cq, 1, &ret);
        HENSURE_ERRNO(num_completions >= 0);

        if(num_completions == 0)
        {
            m_polling = false;
            goto start;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!ignore_errors && ret.status != IBV_WC_SUCCESS)
            {
                FATAL_ERROR("Failed status %s (%d) for wr_id %d\n",
                            ibv_wc_status_str(ret.status),
                            ret.status,
                            (int) ret.wr_id);
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ibv_get_cq_event()` is thread safe. Internally it is just calling the underlying Linux `read` system call, and that will only return an event to one thread at a time. I'm not sure your code is doing exactly what you want, because calling `ibv_req_notify_cq()` before consuming any CQ entries will likely immediately generate another CQ event and wake up another polling thread (and that thread may generate another event, waking up another thread...).

In general all libibverbs functions are designed to be thread safe unless locking requirements are explicitly called out in the documentation (for example the `mlx5dv` interface provides for applications that want to manage locking themselves to maximize performance).

Comment: My goal is to get the next CQ event, in the most performant way in a multithreaded environment.  Do you think putting `ibv_req_notify_cq` at the end of the function will be more performant?

Comment: are you sure you want to use events?
if you are really after performance and you have steady flow of CQEs, you may want to consider polling mode.
if your traffic is better characterized by 'bursts' you still may want to arm CQ only when there are no CQEs left there.
also, performance hint: you may save quite a few microseconds (or more) by polling more than 1 CQE at once.